# Dynamically Name Objects In Java ArrayLists

Tags: java, object, arraylist

How would I go about naming an object dynamically in an `ArrayList`. So I have this:

```
        optionNum = input.nextInt();
        switch (optionNum) {
            case 1: //Customer Information Retrieval
                    int i = 0;
                    System.out.println("What is the customer ID");
                        customerId = input.next();
                        newCustomer.setcustomerId(customerId);
                    System.out.println("What is the customer first name?");
                        firstName = input.next();
                        newCustomer.setfirstName(firstName);
                    System.out.println("What is the customer last name?");
                        lastName = input.next();
                        newCustomer.setlastName(lastName);
                    System.out.println("What is the customer age?");
                        age = input.nextInt();
                        newCustomer.setAge(age);
                    System.out.println("What is the customer income?");
                        income = input.nextDouble();
                        newCustomer.setIncome(income);
                    System.out.println("What is the customer credit score?");
                        creditScore= input.nextInt();
                        newCustomer.setcreditScore(creditScore);
                    newCustomer.Attributes(customerId, firstName, lastName, age, income, creditScore);
                    customers.add(i, newCustomer);
                    i++;
                    break;
```

And it is within a do while loop, but every time I add a new customer it overwrites the old customer leaving me with two customers with the same information. How do I go about having it create a new object with each iteration of the loop?

Comment: You're not sharing enough code, but for creating a new object, you need to use the `new` keyword for invoking the constructor somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create newCustomer object inside the case block, rather than outside. You are basically overwriting the same object  causing the previous values to be overwritten whereas a new entry is also made each time in the list.

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare customer before loop : 
    Customer newCustomer =null; 
2) Inside a loop create customer instance and set in     newCustomer object. 
    newCustomer =  new Customer();
3) fill customer object
4) add it to customers list

Hope this helps you!!!